# Select box automatically opens on clicking button in Chrome Android and Chrome Responsive Mode using IONIC FRAMEWORK

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

### Short description of the problem:

I have a form in which a group of fields in repeated based on an array of objects.
There is a button which pushes an object into the array. So the user can add as many groups as he like one by one.
There is a select box as the first element of this group.

However, upon clicking the button, the select box is opened automatically after the new group appears.

**Steps to reproduce:**
1. Visit http://52.66.117.243/app-test/ for testing.
2. Scroll down and click on add more button.
3. The new select box for title automatically opens
 Chrome in responsive mode is also able to reproduce the problem

I think the issue might be due to the click event passed on to the newly added select box since the position w.r.t screen of the button is occupied by the new select element. However, I cannot be very sure.

Interestingly, a small timeout before adding of the new elements seems to solve the problem.

If the problem is indeed the click event being propagated, can someone be kind enough to explain what is causing it, event bubbling/capturing on the ng-click or something else ?

Thank you.